# Do Enums in Dart have comparison operators?

Tags: dart

I come from a Kotlin background and I used to the fact that enums there implements `Comparable`, which allows me do something like below:

Given a enum

```
enum class Fruit{
  APPLE,
  BANANA,
  ORANGE,
}
```

I could use the operators `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=`, to compare any occurrence of this enum, like:

```
APPLE < BANANA -> true
ORANGE < BANANA -> false
```

I wonder if dart has the same by default or if I have to define custom operators to any enum I might need that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to check [`Enum` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Enum-class.html) or try it yourself to see that `Enum` classes do not provide `operator <`, `operator >`, etc.

Dart 2.15 does add an [`Enum.compareByIndex`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Enum/compareByIndex.html) method, and you also can add extension methods to `Enum`s:

```dart
extension EnumComparisonOperators<T extends Enum> on T {
  bool operator <(T other) {
    return index < other.index;
  }

  bool operator <=(T other) {
    return index <= other.index;
  }

  bool operator >(T other) {
    return index > other.index;
  }

  bool operator >=(T other) {
    return index >= other.index;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use the extension of the enum? Because I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @Forgotten-Storm Using the OP's example, you'd just do, say, `Fruit.APPLE < Fruit.BANANA`. "Couldn't make it work" is non-descriptive; please elaborate about what specific problem you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in other comments, you can also create your own operator and use it.

Try the code below to see how to handle it without creating an operator.

```
enum Fruit{
  APPLE,
  BANANA,
  ORANGE,
}

void main() {

  print(Fruit.APPLE.index == 0);
  print(Fruit.BANANA.index == 1);
  print(Fruit.ORANGE.index == 2);
  
  if( Fruit.APPLE.index < Fruit.BANANA.index ){
    // Write your code here
    print("Example");
  }
  
}
```

result

```dart
true
true
true
Example
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define your own order, then this is a simple and compact solution:

```
enum Fruit {
  APPLE, // index 0
  BANANA, // index 1
  ORANGE; // index 2

  bool operator >(Similarity other) => index > other.index; 
  bool operator <(Similarity other) => index < other.index;
  bool operator >=(Similarity other) => index >= other.index;
  bool operator <=(Similarity other) => index <= other.index;
}
```

Note that the order is reversed. `ORANGE > BANANA = true`

If you want to compare the words APPLE, BANANA and ORANGE instead, then you can use this:

```
enum Fruit {
  APPLE,
  BANANA,
  ORANGE;

  bool operator >(Similarity other) => toString().compareTo(other.toString()) > 0;
  bool operator <(Similarity other) => toString().compareTo(other.toString()) < 0;
  bool operator >=(Similarity other) => toString().compareTo(other.toString()) >= 0;
  bool operator <=(Similarity other) => toString().compareTo(other.toString()) <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.15, statically:

```
compareByIndex<T extends Enum>(T value1, T value2) → int
    Compares two enum values by their index. [...]
    @Since("2.15")
compareByName<T extends Enum>(T value1, T value2) → int
    Compares enum values by name. [...]
    @Since("2.15")
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Enum-class.html